# Fallo Desplazamiento vertical en un notebook con rueda del raton - Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

Os pongo rápidamente en detalle como llevo el código y cuando me funciona y cuando deja de funcionar(código abajo o en github: [ejemplo](https://github.com/BotB0t/prueba_vertical_scroll_tk)).

La cosa es que si vuelco el frame en un notebook, el scroll (***con la rueda del ratón***) no funciona en toda la 'página', éste se pierde cuando el raton esta dentro de un **LabelFrame** y funciona bien cuando se encuentra encima del frame del fondo.

***El código del vertical scroll funciona correctamente cuando solo muestro el frame de la vista por pantalla, pasándole el 'root' como 'parent'.***

Gracias de ante mano.

**scroll_controller.py** *Lleva el control del desplazamiento cuando se le aplica a un frame*

```
import tkinter as tk

class VerticalScrolledFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kw):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kw)

        self._vscrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
        self._vscrollbar.pack(fill=tk.Y, side=tk.RIGHT, expand=tk.FALSE)
        self._canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bd=0, highlightthickness=0,
                                 yscrollcommand=self._vscrollbar.set)
        self._canvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=tk.TRUE)
        self._vscrollbar.config(command=self._canvas.yview)

        self._canvas.xview_moveto(0)
        self._canvas.yview_moveto(0)

        self._inner_frame = tk.Frame(self._canvas, bg='#FFF4DC')
        self._inner_id = self._canvas.create_window(0, 0,
                                                    window=self._inner_frame,
                                                    anchor=tk.NW
                                                    )
        self._inner_frame.bind("<MouseWheel>", self._on_mousewheel)
        self._inner_frame.bind('<Configure>', self._configure_inner)
        self._canvas.bind('<Configure>', self._configure_canvas)

    @property
    def container(self):
        return self._inner_frame

    def _configure_canvas(self, event):
        width = max(self._inner_frame.winfo_reqwidth(), self._canvas.winfo_width())
        height = max(self._inner_frame.winfo_reqheight(), self._canvas.winfo_height())
        self._canvas.itemconfigure(self._inner_id, width=width, height=height)

    def _configure_inner(self, event):
        self._canvas.configure(scrollregion=self._canvas.bbox("all"))

    def _on_mousewheel(self, event):
        self._canvas.yview_scroll(int(-1 * (event.delta / 120)), "units")
        return "break"
```

**tab1_controller.py** *Es el controlador de la vista que quiero volcar en el notebook*

```
from tab1_view import Tab1_View

class Tab1_Controller:
    def __init__(self, parent, notebook_controller):
        self.parent = parent
        self.notebook_controller= notebook_controller
        self.view = Tab1_View(parent, self)

    def click_button_buscar(self):
        pass
```

**tab1_view.py** *Este fichero contiene el interfaz del frame*

```
from tkinter import ttk

try:
    from six.moves import tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    raise ImportError("Se requiere el modulo Tkinter")

import scroll_controller

class Tab1_View(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller, *args, **kwargs):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.controller = controller

    """Esto es el desplazamiento (scroll) vertical"""
    self.frame_tab1 = scroll_controller.VerticalScrolledFrame(self.parent)
    self.frame_tab1.pack(expand=True, fill='both')
    self.parent.bind("<MouseWheel>", self.frame_tab1._on_mousewheel)

    #############################################################################
    #   Labelframe 1
    #############################################################################
    self.image_loupe = tk.PhotoImage(file="loupe.png")
    self.label_loupe = tk.Label(self.frame_tab1.container, text="BUSQUEDA  ", compound='right',
                                image=self.image_loupe)
    self.labelFrame1 = tk.LabelFrame(self.frame_tab1.container, labelwidget=self.label_loupe,
                                     padx=30, pady=30, labelanchor='n')
    self.labelFrame1.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.labelFrame1.grid_columnconfigure(7, weight=1)
    self.labelFrame1.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.labelFrame1.grid_rowconfigure(5, weight=1)

    self.label_keywords = tk.Label(self.labelFrame1, text="Palabras a buscar: ")
    self.entry_keyword = tk.Entry(self.labelFrame1, relief=tk.GROOVE, bd=2)

    self.label_keywords.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='ne', padx=2, pady=10)
    self.entry_keyword.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky='nw', padx=2, pady=12)
    #############################################################################

    #############################################################################
    #   Labelframe 2
    #############################################################################
    self.image_loupe = tk.PhotoImage(file="loupe.png")
    self.label_loupe = tk.Label(self.frame_tab1.container, text="BUSQUEDA  ", compound='right',
                                image=self.image_loupe)
    self.labelFrame2 = tk.LabelFrame(self.frame_tab1.container, labelwidget=self.label_loupe,
                                     padx=30, pady=30, labelanchor='n')
    self.labelFrame2.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.labelFrame2.grid_columnconfigure(7, weight=1)
    self.labelFrame2.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.labelFrame2.grid_rowconfigure(5, weight=1)

    self.label_keywords = tk.Label(self.labelFrame2, text="Palabras a buscar: ")
    self.entry_keyword = tk.Entry(self.labelFrame2, relief=tk.GROOVE, bd=2)

    self.label_keywords.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='ne', padx=2, pady=10)
    self.entry_keyword.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky='nw', padx=2, pady=12)
    #############################################################################

    #############################################################################
    #   Labelframe 3
    #############################################################################
    self.image_loupe = tk.PhotoImage(file="loupe.png")
    self.label_loupe = tk.Label(self.frame_tab1.container, text="BUSQUEDA  ", compound='right',
                                image=self.image_loupe)
    self.labelFrame3 = tk.LabelFrame(self.frame_tab1.container, labelwidget=self.label_loupe,
                                     padx=30, pady=30, labelanchor='n')
    self.labelFrame3.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.labelFrame3.grid_columnconfigure(7, weight=1)
    self.labelFrame3.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.labelFrame3.grid_rowconfigure(5, weight=1)

    self.label_keywords = tk.Label(self.labelFrame3, text="Palabras a buscar: ")
    self.entry_keyword = tk.Entry(self.labelFrame3, relief=tk.GROOVE, bd=2)

    self.label_keywords.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='ne', padx=2, pady=10)
    self.entry_keyword.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky='nw', padx=2, pady=12)
    #############################################################################

     # Button del frame
    #############################################################################
    self.button_buscar = tk.Button(self.frame_tab1.container, cursor="hand2", command=controller.click_button_buscar,
                                   text="BUSCAR")

    # Colocamos los Labelframe
    #############################################################################
    self.labelFrame1.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.X, padx=15, pady=15)
    self.labelFrame2.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.X, padx=15, pady=15)
    self.labelFrame3.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.X, padx=15, pady=15)
    #############################################################################
    self.button_buscar.pack(pady=20)
```

**main.py** *Ejecución del programa - ESTE NO FUNCIONA CORRECTAMENTE*

```
from tkinter import ttk

try:
    from six.moves import tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    raise ImportError("Se requiere el modulo Tkinter")

from tab1_view import *
from tab1_controller import *
from scroll_controller import *


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.minsize(900,400)

    nb = ttk.Notebook(root)
    frame_nb = tk.Frame(nb)

    Tab1_Controller(frame_nb, nb)

    nb.add(frame_nb, text='tab1')
    nb.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

    root.mainloop()
```

**main.py** *Ejecución del programa - AQUI SI FUNCIONA CORRECTAMENTE EL SCROLL*

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
root = tk.Tk()
root.minsize(900,400)

nb = ttk.Notebook(root) # Creo el notebook para pasarselo como parámetro, y no reedefinir código

Tab1_Controller(root, nb)

root.mainloop()
```